# Pandas pivot table or groupby absolute maximum of column

Tags: pandas, python-3.8

I have a dataframe df as:

```
Col1    Col2
A      -5
A       3
B      -2
B       15
```

I need to get the following:

```
Col1    Col2
A      -5
B       15
```

Where the decision was made for each group in `Col1` by selecting the absolute maximum from `Col2`. I am not sure how to proceed with this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`DataFrameGroupBy.idxmax`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.idxmax.html) with pass absolute values for indices and then select by [`DataFrame.loc`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html):

```
df = df.loc[df['Col2'].abs().groupby(df['Col1']).idxmax()]
#alternative with reassign column
df = df.loc[df.assign(Col2 = df['Col2'].abs()).groupby('Col1')['Col2'].idxmax()]
print (df)
  Col1  Col2
0    A    -5
3    B    15
```